# Clearing Out Sections of Page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've re-made a HTML site using JavaScript, I've completed one page and have two others. I want to ensure that before the new content is loaded with a button click that the content before it was cleared and the content area is fresh to put the new content in. This is [the code](https://codeshare.io/5ergla).

In the beginning what would happen is the second function would come in under the footer and expand the page downward, I added an if statement to  stop it coming in however I cannot clear the page and get each function to come in fresh.

```
var x = document.getElementById("mainWindow");
var checker1 = document.getElementById("About1");
if(checker1 != null) {
  x.removeChild().getElementByID("About1");
  x.removeChild().getElementByID("About2");
  x.removeChild().getElementByID("player");
}
```

Comment: When you navigate to a new URL, the old page is unloaded. You don't need to check for that.

Comment: @ScottMarcus It doesnt change the URL, its on an event, it just changes the elements of the page

Comment: If you just want to make sure that an area of the page is cleared out so new content can be injected in that area, just set that area's wrapper element's `innerHTML` to `""`

Comment: @ScottMarcus A very simple solution.....I was trying to make it more complicated, if you add that as an answer I will tick it, thanks :)

Comment: Check out example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your content that needs to go away is wrapped by some element, just clear the entire thing like this:

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");

document.getElementById("btnClear").addEventListener("click", function(){
  // Clear the contents of the wrapper element:
  wrapper.innerHTML = "";
});
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <h1>The heading</h1>
  <p>Some details</p>
  <ul>
    <li>data</li>
    <li>data</li>
    <li>data</li>    
  </ul>
</div>

<button id="btnClear">Clear</button>
```